# Need to change a SPAN ID upon page load

Tags: javascript

I have a very basic FireFox Extension that I need to change a SPAN ID when the page loads.

```
<span id="FormAssistStatus">On</span>
```

I just need that to be Off, rather than On.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `onload` event and change your required HTML inside it:

```js
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('FormAssistStatus').innerHTML ="off";
};
```

```html
<span id="FormAssistStatus">On</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback!  It's a good new, bad news situation.  The scripts provided got the job done, however there's something else on the page that's causing the content to still be displayed.

However, I just wanted to say y'all rock!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementById('FormAssistStatus').textContent = 'Off';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
document.getElementById("FormAssistStatus").textContent = "Off";
```

Add `"run_at": "document_end"` to `content_scripts` in your `manifest.json`.